# While implementing Maps in Xamarin, I got following Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Comment: by closing Visual Studio, reopening it and cleaning and rebuilding the entire solution. It is possible solution, If any one know more on it please let me know.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question body with some resources *(like Xamarin.Forms.Targets)*